# Export of the matrix in a order?

Tags: list-manipulation, export, output-formatting

I want to export the following matrix,

```
MatrixForm[Flatten /@Table[{f[a, b, c], a, b, c}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {c, 0, 2}]]
```

is there any way to export the first four columns and the next four columns below to the first exported columns?

So the one exported file (.dat or .txt) contains only 4 columns with many rows.

something like,

```
f[0,0,0] 0 0 0
f[1,0,0] 1 0 0
f[2,0,0] 2 0 0
f[0,0,1] 0 0 1
f[1,0,0] 1 0 1
f[2,0,1] 2 0 1
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use `Transpose` and remove `MatrixForm`.

Comment: Then `Export["file.txt", matrix, "List"]` should do the trick.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher no, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Export[
 "file.txt",
 Flatten[Transpose[
   Table[{f[a, b, c], a, b, c}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {c, 0, 2}], {3, 
    1, 2}], 2],
 "Table"
 ]
```